# Firebase / Firestore emulator not accessible over local network

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, localhost, firebase-tools

My app fails to connect to the Firestore emulator over the local network. I can access Firestore fine on the same PC the emulator is running on (localhost essentially), but when I test the app over the local network on my iPhone (http://192.168.1.23) anything to do with Firestore fails.

My code in `firebase.json` is:

```
"emulators": {
   "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
   }
}
```

And in my `firebaseInit.js` file it's `connectFirestoreEmulator(db, 'localhost', 8080)`

In `firebase.json` I've tried adding a `host` property as follows:

```
"emulators": {
   "firestore": {
      "port": 8080,
      "host": "192.168.1.23"
   }
}
```

...and I've also tried `"host":"http://192.168.1.23"` and `"host":"0.0.0.0"`

In my `firebaseInit.js` file I've also tried:

```
connectFirestoreEmulator(db, '192.168.1.23', 8080)
```

and

```
connectFirestoreEmulator(db, 'http://192.168.1.23', 8080)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Checks I would do: ping the 192.168.1.23 IP, open a telnet session to 192.168.1.23, port 8080, check if there is any firewall that is blocking connections to port 8080

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it; I must've missed this particular configuration when I was trying different hosts and ports in various places. But for me it now works with `firebase.json` file as:

```
"emulators": {
    "firestore": {
      "host": "192.168.1.23",
      "port": 8080
    },
```

...and `firebaseInit.js` file with the line:

`connectFirestoreEmulator(db, '192.168.1.23', 8080)`

Not sure how I missed this specific combination but I'll leave this here for anyone else who has this problem. Thanks all.